# animate image/UIView iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

On the homepage of my application I want to animate a PNG image sliding into the view, then sliding out again before a second image slides in, then out. Time just for the viewer to read before each disappears. I dont know how to do this and would like some input ? seems pretty simple I hope it is and someone can direct me how to do it. I also want it on loop, so whenever you go back to the screen it will animate still.

Any ideas please? Only a day or so to finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less just expanding on Tom van Zummeren's answer. This should be enough to get the basic idea across.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, -280, 280, 280)];
    [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:myImageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [myImageView setCenter:self.view.center];
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            [myImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(myImageView.center.x, self.view.bounds.size.height + (myImageView.bounds.size.height / 2))];
        }completion:^(BOOL done){
            [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, -280, 280, 280)];
            NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(myImageView.frame));
            [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks that is outlined to me now and I can work on it cheers

Comment: needs a bit of work, rather than vertical, how do I get horizontal? across the screen, its almost what I want, need to tweak a little, + make the image not become squashed

Comment: + second image, cant get to appear.. any further input please?

Comment: Iknow but im still beginner, where am I to find information from guides on how to animate image views...

Comment: @holtii Sorry, I didn't mean for that to sound quite that hostile. What you'll want to look into is the usages of `CGRectMake` in this code. These are what tell is where to put an object on screen. And the second image doesn't appear because no additional animation is triggered. After image1 goes off screen, this code resets it to its original position and then changes the image in the image view, but never animates it back on screen

Comment: okay thanks, I will look into that and try to figure myself thanks for answering, Will mark too

Comment: sort of giving up, not got the time to be searching for answers which I cannot find. should be simple from the code you supplied :/ with more time I would continue looking

Comment: could you not just help a little more?  I cant find information on how to make it go across, also adding the second and making it loop. I just dont know :S

Answer (score 1):

You can use Core Animation for this. It's real easy to do. Example animation:

```
UIImageView *imageView = ...;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-160, 100, 250, 200);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 250, 200);
}];
```

This animates a `UIImageView` from x-coordinate -160 to 160 in 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Do you have any reason for animating the frame when you are not changing the size of the view? Why not simply animate the `center` property? (Also, that's UIView animations and not Core Animation)

Comment: Center is fine too. I don't mind. And it IS core animation but with a thin UIKit abstraction layer on top of it.

Comment: By that logic it's OpenGL ES as well :D

Comment: I just see it as a shorthand notation of "real" Core Animation code which usually spans several lines of code. If you want to call that UIView animations that's fine. Core Animation sounds more awesome :P

Comment: which parameter to go across the screen? not vertical.. :/

Comment: it's this: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height) where x is horizontal and y is vertical

Comment: confused, I have 1 image that comes from the top down the screen, but i want it to go across, followed by a second image, then want it to loop, having trouble

Answer (score 0):

**//Starting point**

```
pImgFlowing.frame = CGRectMake(544, 817, 84, 18);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
```

**//Ending point**

```
pImgFlowing.frame = CGRectMake(544, 774, 84, 61);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```